# android + piconets + parked devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, network-protocols

i am trying to code an application with android and bluetooth. As a summary, and as something i think is well documented on internet, bluetooth 2.1 (i couldnt find information for 3.0 and 4.0) only supports 7 active devices in the same piconet, and up to 255 in parked mode (not connected and discovered through Inquiry scan, buy sync listening for broadcast packets). I couldn't find information for 3.0 and 4.0 specifications if they continue with this limitation of 7 active members.

There are tons of questions which answers are not easy to find about bluetooth. I hope somebody can help me with the next issue.

How can you communicate with a device in parked mode in Android through RFCOMM? If only 7 devices can be active with open socket connection (paged & connected), how can you make all devices being able to communicate between each other through the master device?

To make things a little bit clear, we can imagine that i am trying to create a communication app between all devices in a piconet, where all users near the master can enter the 'chat'. But to make all of them chat, you need all devices (connected and parked) 'connected' through RFCOMM, so they can exchange information using sockets.

But if only 7 can communicate and can open an active socket, how could be the strategy? How can i make all of them communicate between each other, so all devices can receive the same information to talk through the chat?

thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The number of active and parked devices remain the same with Bluetooth 3.0 also, Bluetooth 4.0 is a little different since it has 2 modes - Bluetooth 4.0 adds a new radio mechanism to Bluetooth called Bluetooth Low Energy, so there are devices that can do dual mode , i.e the classic Bluetooth (2.1, 3.0 functions) and the new Low Energy functions, Some devices will be Low energy function only and some will be dual mode being able to do both Low Energy mode and classic bluetooth.

The Classic Bluetooth capabilities remain mostly the same in 4.0 also, the Low Energy is a completely new option, The Low Energy option (radio) cannot communicate with the classic option. (Unless it is dual mode having both classic and low energy options)

Now the above theory was important because in case of low energy there are no active devices  restrictions, theoretically you have have hundreds of thousands of devices (assuming they talk at non overlapping intervals) connected. (Unlike Classic where the limit was 7), In Low Energy there are no special modes like Park either. Low Energy is typically for sensor devices which at some interval wake up connect send some data and go away. They are typically low bandwidth and short duration communication. This makes the low energy option attractive and wireless sensors can work off coin cell batteries for years.

Now to answer the rest of the Questions:
- You cannot communicate directly with Parked devices, there is a broadcast mechanism to send (one way) data (unreliably) to parked devices, Android does not have any API support for it. In addition I will discourage usage of Park since it is a complicated procedure and prone to interoperability issues with radios of different vendors, in addition the Park mode is deprecated in the latest versions of Bluetooth.

The alternative is to un-park devices one after the other - make them active - complete the communication in active mode and then park them back.
This may make your group chat application handling complicated.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. Just to make things clear, you are saying that the only option to communicate with non active devices is to disconnect from one device already connected, so now, you can turn the old parked one into active state,right? One question. If i understood correctly bluetooth protocol, a master device can handle up to 255 parked devices, but if i want all of them active, the only idea i got is trying to make all of them being part of a scatternet network. What do you think about it? in other words, in stead of putting the device number 8 and above in parked mode,

Comment: make the rest of devices (255-8) create more masters and slaves, and form a scatternet in stead of a piconet.

what do you think about it? I dont know if this can be done, because i dont understand how bluetooth stack protocol manages the creation of scatternets with piconets, but you are the master of bluetooth here on stackoverflow, so i am sure you can give me an answer :-).

Comment: Bluetooth can handle more than 255 parked devices, the number can be arbitarily large theoritically. It can have only 7 active devices, you can park an active device and then unpark a parked device etc, the only restriction is that at a time only 7 can be active. Scatternets are more complicated depending on your application it can be useful. Devices mostly support only limited scatternet, so I think you can may be in scatternet mode handle up to 9 or 10 active devices.

Comment: Hi Dennis. I still dont understand who manages and creates the scatternet. The bluetooth stack protocol or the application made by the programmer? i would need to create a scatternet, so like this way, i can make all devices to be put as 'active', and communicate between each other 'on real time', but i cant find information about it on internet, and less about android. I hope you can help me with this. thank you very much in advance Dennis.